# How to write JSDoc correctly for an inline function that modified the String prototype?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How do I properly document functions that extend the String object prototype? For example:

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
    /**
     * @name String.prototype.format
     * Replaces symbols like {0}, {1} in a string with the values from the arguments.
     */
    String.prototype.format = function () {
        var args = arguments;
        return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
              ? args[number]
              : match
            ;
        });
    };
}
```

I tried both with and without the @function and @name comment.

It doesn't work in the sense that Visual Studio 2017 doesn't begin to show a tooltip with the function's description, as it normally does when adding a JSDoc comment.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
    /**
     * @namespace String
     */

    /**
     * @memberof String
     * @name String#format
     * @function
     * Replaces symbols like {0}, {1} in a string with the values from the arguments.
     */
    String.prototype.format = function () {
        var args = arguments;
        return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
              ? args[number]
              : match
            ;
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't in Visual Studio 2017, although it seems like a proper way to document it.

Comment: Try removing `@name` line and changing `@function` to `@function format`